# Visualforce page to display detail task/activtiy chronology

Tags: apex, visualforce, tasks, activities, activityhistory

I'd like to know and could you please advise how the following functionality can be achieved in Salesforce:
When a Salesforce user opens a task, he/she will have to monitor and observe what happened and when.

Comment: Why are you sabotaging your own posts? Please stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasks are related to a particular record and you cannot have parent child/lookup  relationship to the standard task object.

However if these tasks are related to some other record say Lead or Opportunity. You can show this representation by embedding custom pages in standard record view.

For this, you need to:

1. Create a custom VF page and make sure that the VF page should have standard controller corresponding to the record on which you want to embed this page
2. Query all the tasks which are related to the record
3. show in the required format using VF tags or custom HTML

Chatter would also show tasks in chronological order. You can also enable feed based layouts which shows chronological view of tasks and chatter actions.